# Inheritance mapping for creating tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, oop

I have the following classes: `Transacao`

```
using System;

namespace ProjetoModeloDDD.Entities
{
    public class Transacao
    {
        public int TransacaoId { get; set; }
        public int Quantidade { get; set; }
        public DateTime Data { get; set; }
        public string Tipo { get; set; }

        public int ProdutoId { get; set; }
        public virtual Produto Produto { get; set; }

        public decimal ValorTotal<T>(int quantidade, Produto produto)
            where T : class
        {
            Quantidade = quantidade;
            Produto = produto;

            return quantidade * produto.Valor;
        }

    }
}
```

`Compra`:

```
namespace ProjetoModeloDDD.Entities
{
    public class Compra : Transacao
    {
        public int TransacaoId { get; set; }
        public virtual Transacao Transacao { get; set; }

        public int FornecedorId { get; set; }
        public virtual Fornecedor Fornecedor { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I want to make a mapping where I will create only the Purchase table in the database, inheriting all Transaction attributes, including `ValorTotal`. I'm doing the configuration below:

```
using ProjetoModeloDDD.Entities;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;


namespace ProjetoModeloDDD.Infra.Data.EntityConfig
{
    public class CompraConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Compra>
    {
        public CompraConfiguration()
        {
            HasKey(c => c.TransacaoId);


            HasRequired(c => c.Produto)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(c => c.ProdutoId);

            HasRequired(c => c.Fornecedor)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(c => c.FornecedorId);

        }

    }
}
```

However, that way I can't even create the purchase table. Could someone give me some guidance regarding this?

Comment: It looks like you want to create a many to many table with `Compra`, but it doesn't make sense to have it inherit from `Transacao`.  Alternatively you could have a collection of `Fornecedor` in `Transacao` and a collection of `Transacao` in `Fornecedor` instead.  Also why is `ValorTotal` generic when you don't even use the generic type?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I have another class, similar to buying, that would inherit all transaction attributes, so I wanted to make the inheritance, so I wouldn't have to write the same code in sales and purchases.